# Don't load Gnome at boot

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I do not want the Gnome to load when my Ubuntu system starts, rather it just load the command line.

In older versions of Ubuntu I used to use the services utility to stop GDM from loading.

How do I do this in 11.04?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to disable GDM by entering the following command:

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee -a /etc/init/gdm.override
```